# IBM Watson Conversation Starter Kit wlServerHost Error

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst, watson-conversation, watson

I downloaded the [Watson Chatbot Starter Kit](https://github.com/ibm-bluemix-mobile-services/starter-mfp-watson-conversation/blob/master/android/README.md#summary) and set the conversation to the Car Sample Template. After adding the required credentials and Workspace ID, I tried running the application. However it shows the following error and stops:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ibm.watson_conversation/com.ibm.watson_conversation.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: You must specify the server host (wlServerHost) in the client configuration file (mfpclient.properties).
```

The mfp.client.properties file is as follows and has no value set for wlServerHost.

```
wlServerProtocol=https
wlServerHost=
wlServerPort=443
wlServerContext=/mfp/
languagePreferences=en
```

I tried setting the IP values I got from ipconfig, in which case the application runs but on sending a message, the chatbot doesn't reply and after a while shows "Connection timed out".I also tried entering the value for wlServerHost as localhost which results in the app stopping.

What value should I have to put for the wlServerHost?

Comment: This will be the hostname/IP of the server. You need to provide the hostname of your server - the IBM MobileFirst Foundation service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mfpclient.properties gets filled with the appropriate values of your MobileFirst server instance when you execute the shell script by name `mfpstartersetup.sh`.

In case you don't see it after executing the shell script, you can navigate to your Watson Chatbot workspace and obtain your MobileFirst server instance's details and fill the mfpclient.properties manually.